# редирект с несуществующей картинки

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Доброго времени суток.
Не могу сделать редирект с несуществующей картинки, есть правило в htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/logos/[0-9]+\.[a-z]+$ images/noLogo.png [L]
```

которое наотрез отказывается работать. На локалхосте все на ура. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте изменить название картинки на no_logo.png

Comment: без разницы(

Comment: Еще есть правила в .htaccess?

Comment: KaZaца, да есть, но они никак не "мешают" этому

Answer (score 1):

Может я напишу бред, но... попробуйте вместо images/noLogo.png написать /images/noLogo.png

А еще проверьте имя вашей картинки и попробуйте вариант nologo.png и конечно имя смените у картинки на сервере.

Если еще что придет в голову допишу, однако сразу предупреждаю я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в mod_rewrite.

Comment: все уже перепробовал... Кстати если делать запросы типа "images/logos/231123.ggg", ну или подобный с неизвестным расширением, то все отлично редиректится на "images/noLogo.png" %)... Гуглил по этой теме, узнал, что сервер nginx стоит до апача и сам занимается статикой типа картинок, архивов, скриптов, стилей и по этому при запросе картинки выдаёт свою страницу ошибки 404.... Короче я в ауте, думаю решения тут вообще нет, ну если только просить хостера настроить по другому сервер.... :(

Comment: попросите хостера, чтобы при отсутствии файла статики запрос проходил далее, я думаю это не сложно. хотя по моему если у вас прокси стоит, он все равно должен получать от бекэнда картинку, если htaccess правильно настроен. мне кажется дело в регулярке, но пока не могу сказать в чем

Answer (score 0):

> В чем может быть проблема?

судя по комментариям, на сервере до *apache* используется ещё и *nginx*.

вероятно, в его настройках указано, что, если файл не существует, возвращать ответ с кодом 404.